# Cannot call method 'scrollTo' of undefined

Tags: jquery, iscroll4

I want an iScroll to scroll to a certain location on page load, I put this code in the very bottom of my footer.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

myScroll.scrollTo(0, -1389, 200);


                   });
</script>
```

But am getting this error in Chrome

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'scrollTo' of undefined**

when I execute

```
  myScroll.scrollTo(0, -1389, 200);
```

alone on the command line it works fine, the document scrolls to the right location.

myScroll is set when iScroll is instantiated, this code is in the header

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
               var myScroll;
function loaded() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        myScroll = new iScroll('content');
    }, 100);
}
window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
            </script>
```

Comment: Where do you set `myScroll`? Can you provide that code?

Comment: edited question to provide code

Comment: issue is resolved i had to wrap it in a timout funciton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a scope issue in that "myScroll" is not within the scope of your defined function. If it's a DOM element, you should probably get the element and define it as myScroll within the scope of your function and then call the scrollTo() function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    myScroll = /* Get your element here */;
    myScroll.scrollTo(0, -1389, 200);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could try "myScroll = document.getElementById('content');" ?

Comment: this wont work because myScroll is an instantiation of the iScroll plugin,

Comment: why would it run from the console but nowhere in the document?